# convert 2 String to 2 Array, result Odd and Even,number In java 7

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-conversion

I have 2 strings s=“Spring" and  s2 = "Festival". I want to print the even letters  from s and the odd from s2 respectively in java. Is there another way to get the same results I got it using a single loop?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class stringReview {

public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String s="Spring";
        char arr[]=s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Data  [" + i + "]=" + arr[i]);
            }

        }
        String s2 = "Festival";
        char arro[]=s2.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j<arro.length;j++){
            if (j % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("Data  [" + j + "]=" + arro[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

result
Data  [0]=S
Data  [2]=r
Data  [4]=n
Data  [1]=e
Data  [3]=t
Data  [5]=v
Data  [7]=l
```

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *I want to print the odd words* Do you mean the odd letters? Your inputs consist of one word each.

Comment: Yes, the even letters for string s1 = {'S', ' r' ,' n'} odd letters for string S2 = { 'e', 't', 'v', 'l'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.  Simply change how you begin and then increment the for loops

```
            String s="Spring";
            char arr[]=s.toCharArray();

            // start at 0 and increment by 2 gives evens.
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2){
                    System.out.println("Data  [" + i + "]=" + arr[i]);
            }
            String s2 = "Festival";
            char arro[]=s2.toCharArray();

            // start at 1 and increment by 2 gives odds.
            for (int j = 1; j < arro.length; j += 2){
                    System.out.println("Data  [" + j + "]=" + arro[j]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear that the order of your output matters, and I would prefer a single loop over two. Start by finding the length of the longer input word and I would use a `boolean` flag to toggle between even / odd. I also see no need to actually convert the `String` into `char[]`. That is, something like

```
String s1 = "Spring", s2 = "Festival";
int len = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
boolean even = true;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (even && i < s1.length()) {
        System.out.printf("Data[%d]=%c%n", i, s1.charAt(i));
    } else if (!even && i < s2.length()) {
        System.out.printf("Data[%d]=%c%n", i, s2.charAt(i));
    }
    even = !even;
}
```

Outputs

```
Data[0]=S
Data[1]=e
Data[2]=r
Data[3]=t
Data[4]=n
Data[5]=v
Data[7]=l
```

Comment: Elliot F. This is a high level of java 7 coding for a single loop. Would recommended a book or tutorial where I can learn and practice it at your level? .  All I found so far in w3schools and YouTube it is basic for loops.